# What does the error code sw=6D04 mean?

Tags: smartcard, pcsc, winscard

According to [ISO/IEC 7816](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx), there are no `6DXX` code except for `XX=00`, but `6D04` is what I'm getting. Does anyone know or is there a more up-to-date version available?

I don't think, it can be something like "Instruction code not supported or invalid" as the commands seems to be valid: When executing `AB`, then `A` returns `9000` and `B` returns `6D04`. When executing `BA`, then `B` returns `9000` and `A` returns `6D04`.

There may be anything wrong... :(

Comment: No, the 2013 version of ISO 7816-4 still has no other 6D combination, so I would consider  6D04 as non-standard. What does the manual of the operating system of the card you use suggest?